# Using a jquery variable in a href attr

Tags: jquery

I am trying to take the jQuery variables and insert them in to the href attribute.

Here is the jQuery

```
$(".id_container").click(function() {
                        var item_id = $(this).find(".item").val();
                        var std_id = $(this).find(".std").val();
                        var cre_id = $(this).find(".cre").val();
                         $(location).attr('href',"link.php?item=''+item+''&stid=''+std+''&cre=''+cre+''");
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have two single quotes, you should have one double quote, and you don't need the extra quotes at the end:

```
$(location).attr('href',"link.php?item="+item+"&stid="+std+"&cre="+cre);
```

Comment: You are using variables he never defines. -1

Comment: I'm using the same variables he uses, I don't know if they're defined elsewhere or not. The OP's code is used as the starting point, and per the comment, my answer seems to have helped.

Comment: The variables don't matter. I just neded to know that " goes around the jQuery variables; not the ' quotes.